# Create custom google search with options to search the web and my site

Tags: search-engine, google-custom-search

I want to create a custom google search for my site. My requirements are as follows:

1. I need a text box for search and two radio buttons(one for searching my site and other for searching web).
2. Depending on the radio button selected the results should be displayed.
3. I have a separate search results page ('/search').

I know how to create a simple google custom search. But this requirement of providing an option to search the site or web is a little tricky for me.
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue.

I first created a search engine in https://cse.google.com/cse/ for my site and configured it to search the web in Basics tab-> Sites to Search option.
With this the search engine would search the entire web.

The code that I placed on the search results page had something this:

"gcse:searchresults-only as_sitesearch='site to search'"

This is a part of the code that google gives you.

Here the parameter 'as_sitesearch' will control which site is to be searched. When the radio button of Searching the web was selected I did not pass any value to 'as_sitesearch' and when the radio button of Searching my site was selected I passed the site url to 'as_sitesearch'.

This worked for me